# "Arab" or "Arabic" or "Arabian"?

Tags: differences

Are these adjectives interchangeable?

I always hear: 'An Arab man.' but never 'An Arabic man.' and I always hear 'Arabic coffee' but never hear 'Arab coffee.'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As adjectives, the *New Oxford American Dictionary* defines *Arabic* a related to the language or the literature, while *Arab* is the more generic term (“of or relating to Arabia and the people of Arabia”) and *Arabian* is a historical variant of *Arab*.

Some dictionaries (including [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=arabic)) report a wider meaning of *Arabic* as being roughly synonymous with *Arab* and *Arabian*. In some established expressions, like “arabic coffee”, *arabic* is favoured. Note, however, that usage favours “arab cuisine”, for example!

Comment: I've been offered "arab coffee" more than once (though more often it's "Turkish coffee" ..."). None of these should be confused with arabica, which is a species of coffee bean that originated in the Arabian peninsula and Ethiopia.

Comment: F'x: "arabic coffee" is not an established expression. Also, *Arab* and *Arabic* are always capitalized.

Comment: @Jimi: well, “arabic coffee” has more hits than “arab coffee”, and a Wikipedia page… maybe there is something more to this particular one

Comment: @F'x: I was erroneous in my assertion. Sorry!

Comment: @F'x & @Jimi I would check [the discussion page on that one, it's not so clear cut and most people are quick to point to Turkish coffee or Arabica beans rather than some distinct "Arabic Coffee" properly speaking.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Arabic_coffee) First, Wikipedia only has one source referring to "Arabic Coffee" and throughout that source it uses *Arabic* in a generic sense, extending it not only to coffee, but pastries (generally), tables (not the decor, just tables of Arabs), etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would use "Arabic" of the language and literature, and "Arab" otherwise. I wouldn't use "Arabian" except perhaps referring to the the country "Saudi Arabia" - but I would more likely say "Saudi".

I would however use "Arabian" in set historical phrases like The Arabian Nights.

Answer (score 3):

These words are not interchangeable.

- **Arab**: relates to the people, places and culture of [the Arab world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_world). Examples include: *Arab cuisine*, *the Arab League*, *Arabs in the Diaspora*, *Arab influence in Western Music*, etc.
- **Arabic**: specifically relates to the written and spoken language of the Arab world. Examples: *Arabic literature*, *Arabic influences in English*, *dialects of Arabic*, etc.
- **Arabian**: historic or literary in its relation to people or things of the Arab world. Examples: *the Arabian nights*, *under the Arabian moonlight*. A note on usage from [NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1222644#m_en_us1222644):

  > **Arab** is now generally used in reference to people; the use of **Arabian** in this sense is historical

  Current usage of the word, however, is found in these examples: [*Arabian Peninsula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabian_Peninsula), [*Arabian Sea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabian_sea) and [*Arabian [horse]*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabian_horse). Also, the demonym for Saudi Arabia is either *Saudi* or *Saudi Arabian*, not *Arabian*.

---

I initially thought *Arabic coffee* did not exist. *Coffee arabica* or arabica coffee is a major commercial species grown in [East Africa and Latin America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Carte_Coffea_robusta_arabic-2.png) ([originated in Ethiopia and Yemen](http://www.ehow.com/about_5348083_types-arabica-coffee-beans.html)). Ironically, the Arab world is not a major producer of the commodity. [Yemen is the only notable Arab nation that grows coffee (the arabica variety), but it is not a major producer.](http://www.nationalgeographic.com/coffee/map.html#3) However, it seems [*Arabic coffee*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_coffee) is a special exception to the rule. Credit goes to fellow user, [Amanda](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6647/amanda), for enlightening me.

Comment: There's such a thing as "Arabic coffee" but it refers to the style of preparation (using very fine grounds which settle at the bottom of the cup, much like Turkish coffee.)

Comment: @Amanda: As you pointed out in your comment on F'x's answer, it's *Arab coffee* not *Arabic coffee*. Similarly, there is such a thing as *Asian coffee* (to refer to the various coffees of Asia) but no such thing as *Asiatic coffee*.

Comment: @Jimi Oke, the OP said s/he's heard 'Arabic coffee" but never "Arab coffee" -- I was responding to that. I've been offered both (though I've never heard of Asian coffee, except in the most generic sense: "I bought this in Taiwan so it is Asian coffee.") Wikipedia prefers 'Arabic coffee' https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Arabic_coffee

Comment: re: "*Arab: relates to the people, places and culture of the Middle East (except Israel) and North Africa*" There are many cultures in this area who would take exception to that categorisation. I know two Iranians for identify themselves as being Persian and Kurdish respectively. They definitely do not see themselves as Arab.

Comment: @dave: Nice catch. I was trying too hard to define the Arab world, but I've edited accordingly, linking it to a Wikipedia article. Indeed, the Persians, Turks, Kurds, etc, are certainly not Arabs. The Arab World only includes North Africa and the Arabian Peninsula.

Answer (score -1):

Arabic pertains to the language.
Arab is any person whose mother tongue is Arabic. "Arab" does not necessarily involve a relation to Arabia (the Arabian Peninsula). A person born and raised in Brazil to Moroccan parents would be an Arab if, due to those circumstances, his or her mother tongue is Arabic.
Thus, Arabian is not a variant of Arab. The two words have distinct meanings.
Arabian means things or persons directly related to Arabia, a well-defined geographical region.
I am Syrian, and my mother tongue is Arabic, so I am an Arab. But I am not from the Arabian Peninsula, therefore I am not an Arabian person.

Comment: Please supplement your answer with reliable source citations. We expect answers to be supported by independently verifiable facts. Thanks.